# I have a page which I have text fields on. I populate these fields using C# but the contents are not displayed on the page

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2013

I am running SP2013 SP1 August 2016 CU.
I have a solution with a page in it which has some text fields in it.  I write some content to those text fields as the result of a drop down list item being selected, on the same page.  But the contents of those fields (all fields I populate using C#) are not displayed.  Yet, I can debug the code and see those fields being populated.  What am I doing wrong ?  Do I need to refresh the pages (how without losing the drop down list item ).  Or do I use update panels (conditional or unconditional)?

This is the page :-

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sbwCtl" Namespace="ABC.SP.xxxxx.ControlTemplates" Assembly="ABC.SP.xxxxxxxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3405ca806bd3483f" %>

<%@ Register Src="../../../_controltemplates/15/SBW/SBWyyyyyyyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="SBWyyyyyyyyControl" %>
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="sbwUpdatePanel" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="sbw">
                <div id="sbw-banner">
                    <asp:Image ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/sbw/images/sbwbanner.png" runat="server" Width="900px" Height="180px" />
                    <h1>

                    </h1>
                </div>
                  <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Template ID
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Text ID="lblTemplateIdP2" runat="server" ></asp:Text>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Template Display Name
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Text ID="lblTemplateDisplayNameP2" runat="server"></asp:Text>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Template Description
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Text ID="lblTemplateDescriptionP2" runat="server"></asp:Text>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <p style="color:red;font-weight:bold"><asp:Label ID="lblUserArea" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

The code I am using to populate the text Boxes is :-

```
              this.lblTemplateIdP2.Text = CurrentSite.Title;
              this.lblTemplateDIsplayNAmeP2.Text = CurrentSite.Description;
```

SO why are my textboxes not being populated on the screen ?

Thanks

Nigel

More Info as requested by @M.Qassas

```
        public void PopulateSiteDropDown(List<XXXSiteInstance> sitesToBeDisplayed, int selectedItem)
    {
        string sLogSource = " Site - Populate";
         try
        {
            this.ddlSiteDisplayName.Items.Clear();
            this.ddlSiteDisplayName.Items.Add("--");

            foreach (XXXSiteInstance site in sitesToBeDisplayed)
            {
               this.ddlSiteDisplayName.Items.Add(site.Title);
            }
            // Set combo box selected index either to -1 (if selected item is null) or the value of selected item)
            if(selectedItem == null)
                this.ddlSiteDisplayName.SelectedIndex = -1;
            else
                this.ddlSiteDisplayName.SelectedIndex = selectedItem;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sbwLogger.LogError(sLogSource, ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

This is what is called when an Item in the drop down list is selected :

```
        protected void ddlSiteDisplayName_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ddlSiteDisplayName.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            // Set the Current Site Collection name to the changed Value
            this.CurrentProvisioningSiteName = this.ddlSiteDisplayName.SelectedValue.ToString();
            if (this.CurrentProvisioningSiteName == "New")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if(this.CurrentProvisioningSite == -1)  // No Top Level Site Selected yet
                this.CurrentProvisioningSite = this.ddlSiteDisplayName.SelectedIndex - 1;   // cos "0" is "New"
            }
            LoadSiteSettings();
        }
    }
```

Where LoadSiteSettings loads the settings of the item in the drop down list that was selected.

The class of the C# code is as follows :-

public partial class XXXXWizardPage : LayoutsPageBase

Comment: Hi @nigel where you fill your dropdown list ? and what's the action that should happen when an item selected ? should you post full code with more details to can help you faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try updating the update panel on drop down selection

```
sbwUpdatePanel.update();
```

Comment: I presume I need updatemode=conditional on the <asp:UpdatePanel  statement on my .aspx page

Comment: Yes <asp:UpdatePanel ID="sbwUpdatePanel" runat="server" 
        UpdateMode="Conditional">

Comment: That looks as if that was the problem thanks @Robert Lindgren and Sunil sahu